# GcmPubSub subscribe Invalid appInstanceToken:

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i'm recently tried new TOPICs API of Google Cloud Messaging Service. but i always got the error **Invalid appInstanceToken:**

here is the logcat

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid appInstanceToken: 
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub.subscribe(Unknown Source)
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at com.SimDetail.MainActivity$3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:265)
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at com.SimDetail.MainActivity$3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:255)
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-10 22:28:34.674 15742-15983/com.SimDetail W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)**

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you are subscribing with a valid InstanceId token?

Comment: @ArthurThompson yes. it's valid token. but it obtained via old API.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. :)
The GCM Token should be obtain vie new

> `InstanceID API`.

otherwise it throws invalid instance token.
it is not valid with `

> GCM.register()

although it receives PUSH but can not subscribe.

Comment: Please refer to this github: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java#L99-L104