# GCM - pubSub.subscribe not working

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, publish-subscribe

I'm using GCM in my android client and I already can push notification from my App server to Android client.

But I cannot subscribe for a topic I use **pubSub.subscribe** method and pass registration token and custom topic name in the format of "/topics/mytopic".
Here are the thing I'm done so far:

- I wrap the method inside try and catch and it doesn't throw any exceptions.
- I have debugged HTTP via Fiddler but when it does not send any request.
- I try get information of token id via https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IID_TOKEN but it doesn't return any subscribed topics for the client.

here the publish code in android intent service:

```
GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
try
{
    pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/mytopic",null);
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use pubSub= GcmPubSub.getInstance(getBaseContext()) instead "this".

Comment: @Dexter tried it but still not working

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have seen [this example IntentService](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java#L99-L104) which shows how to subscribe to topics. Please check it out and see how far you get - it sounds like something you are trying to do. Check specifically **the way the token string gets created** which is then used in the subscription:

```
 InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
 String token = instanceID.getToken(SENDER_ID,GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

According to the solution to a token issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635944/gcmpubsub-subscribe-invalid-appinstancetoken), obtaining the token has to be via using `InstanceID` - otherwise you get issues with topic subscriptions.

Comment: i know that. i told in my question my problem just in  pubSub.subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Main Thread,you should use another thread
Try adding your subscribe code to AsyncTask or IntentService

Comment: That caught it for me ta